# Determine Nullability Of A Reference Type in C# Using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have .NET Core project using C#-8 and nullable types enabled.

I have the following class

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int? NullableInt { get; private set; }

    public string? NullableString { get; private set; }

    public string NonNullableString { get; private set; }

    public MySubClass? MyNullableSubClass { get; private set; }

}
```

I need to be able to loop through all the properties is the class and determine which properties are nullable.

So The code I have looks like this

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> GetNullableProperties(Type type)
{
    var nullableProperties = new List<string>();
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
       var isNullable = false;
       if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
       {
           isNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null;
       } else {
           var nullableAttribute = property.PropertyType.CustomAttributes
              .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute");
           isNullable = nullableAttribute != null;
       }

       if (isNullable)
       {
           nullableProperties.Add(property.propertyType.Name)
       }
    }
    return nullableProperties;
}
```

Passing the type of `MyClass` to this method returns `["NullableInt", "NullableString", "NonNullableString", "MyNullableSubClass"]`.

However, the expected return value is `["NullableInt", "NullableString", "MyNullableSubClass"]`.

The reason why the `NonNullableString` property is determined to be nullable, is because it has the Nullable attribute on it.

My understanding is that when determining whether a reference type is nullable, you need to check if it has the Nullable attribute. However, this does not seem to be the case for string types. It seems that all strings have the nullable attribute defined on them. Is there a way to  find out if a `string` is nullable (i.e. defined with the nullable operator `?`).

Comment: Possibly this post is a duplicate of the next one: [How to use .NET reflection to check for nullable reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type)

Comment: This is much more complex than any answer here or under the linked question covers. A library called [Namotion.Reflection](https://github.com/RicoSuter/Namotion.Reflection) has an implementation that seems foolproof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the complete solution. We need to check the custom attributes on the property and on the class.

```
...


private const byte NonNullableContextValue = 1;
private const byte NullableContextValue = 2;

public IEnumerable<string> GetNullableProperties(Type type)
{
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
       var isNullable = property.PropertyType.IsValueType
           ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null;
           : IsReferenceTypePropertyNullable(property);

       if (isNullable)
       {
           nullableProperties.Add(property.propertyType.Name)
       }
    }
    return nullableProperties;
}

private function bool IsReferenceTypePropertyNullable(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var classNullableContextAttribute = property.DeclaringType.CustomerProperties
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeType.Name == "NullableContextAttribute")

    var classNullableContext = classNullableContextAttribute
        ?.ConstructorArguments
        .First(ca => ca.ArgumentType.Name == "Byte")
        .Value;

    // EDIT: This logic is not correct for nullable generic types
    var propertyNullableContext = property.CustomAttributes
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute")
        ?.ConstructorArguments
        .First(ca => ca.ArgumentType.Name == "Byte")
        .Value;

    // If the property does not have the nullable attribute then it's 
    // nullability is determined by the declaring class 
    propertyNullableContext ??= classNullableContext;

    // If NullableContextAttribute on class is not set and the property
    // does not have the NullableAttribute, then the proeprty is non nullable
    if (propertyNullableContext == null)
    {
         return true;
    }

    // nullableContext == 0 means context is null oblivious (Ex. Pre C#8)
    // nullableContext == 1 means not nullable
    // nullableContext == 2 means nullable
    switch (propertyNullableContext)
    {
        case NonNullableContextValue:
            return false;
        case NullableContextValue:
            return true;
        default:
            throw new Exception("My error message");
    }
}
```

Here's is some information about the nullable context values: https://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/PostSharp-internals-handling-csharp-8-nullable-reference-types

Comment: I have a blog post here as well that you may find useful: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/02/10/nullableattribute-and-c-8/ - note that it gets pretty complex for generic types.

Comment: I had to identify nullability on just two simple reference types (one being `string`) and I managed to pull it to the end by using a recursive static method which traversed the `DeclaringType` hierarchy upwards, in search of `NullableContextAttribute`. In my case, sometimes that attribute was found further up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check custom attributes in property itself but not in type of property.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNullableProperties(Type type)
    {
        var nullableProperties = new List<string>();
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var isNullable = false;
            if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                isNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null;
            }
            else
            {
                var nullableAttribute = property.CustomAttributes
                   .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute");
                isNullable = nullableAttribute == null;
            }

            if (isNullable)
            {
                nullableProperties.Add(property.Name);
            }
        }
        return nullableProperties;
    }
```

Also, if property is nullable, this attribute is not defined. If property is not nullable, this attribute exists.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. I think the last sentence was supposed to be reversed. Also, there was more to this problem. I also needed to look at the custom attributes on the class. I posted a complete solution below.