# How to identify a nullable reference type for generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In C# 8 with nullable enabled, is there a way to identify a **nullable reference type** for generic type?

For **nullable value type**, there is a section dedicated to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type

We are trying to do optional null check according to the generic type

```cs
#nullable enable
public static Result<T> Create<T>(T value)
{
   if (!typeof(T).IsNullable() && value is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

   // Do something
}

public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
{
   // If type is SomeClass, return false
   // If type is SomeClass?, return true
   // If type is SomeEnum, return false
   // If type is SomeEnum?, return true
   // If type is string, return false
   // If type is string?, return true
   // If type is int, return false
   // If type is int?, return true
   // etc
}
```

So the following will throw `ArgumentNullException` when `T` is not nullable
But allow value to be null with no exception when `T` is nullable, e.g.

```
Create<Anything>(null); // throw ArgumentNullException

Create<Anything?>(null); // No excception
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .NET reflection to check for nullable reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type) You can also have a look at [nullable-metadta](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md) spec

Comment: @JasonYu Do you need to define if reference type is nullable or not?

Comment: @Iliar Turdushev that's what I would like to do. But constraint only work like `where T : notnull`. I want the `Create<T>` method to throw `ArgumentNullException` according to if `T` is nullable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In C# 8 with nullable enabled, is there a way to identify a **nullable
> reference type** for generic type?

***In `C# 8` there is NO way to check if a type parameter passed to a generic method is a nullable reference type or not.***

The problem is that any nullable reference type `T?` is represented by the same type `T` ([but with a compiler-generated attribute annotating it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md)), as opposed to nullable value type `T?` that is represented by the actual .NET type `Nullable<T>`.

When compiler generates code that invokes a generic method `F<T>`, where `T` can be either nullable reference type or not, an information if `T` is nullable refence type is lost. Lets consider the next sample method:

```
public void F<T>(T value) { }
```

For the next invocations

```
F<string>("123");
F<string?>("456");
```

compiler will generate the next `IL` code (I simplified it a bit):

```
call    F<string>("123")
call    F<string>("456")
```

You can see that to the second method a type parameter `string` is passed instead of `string?` because the representation of the nullable reference type `string?` during the execution is the same type `string`.

***Therefore during execution it is impossible to define if a type parameter passed to a generic method is a nullable reference type or not.***

---

I think that for your case an optimal solution would be to pass a `bool` value that will indicate if a reference type is nullable or not. Here is a sample, how it can be implemented:

```
public static Result<T> Create<T>(T value, bool isNullable = false)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    // If type "T" is a value type then we can check if it is nullable or not.
    if (t.IsValueType) 
    {
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null && value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }
    // If type "T" is a reference type then we cannot check if it is nullable or not.
    // In this case we rely on the value of the argument "isNullable".
    else
    {
        if (!isNullable && value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: If a generic type is constrained to "struct" it is constrained to non-nullable value types.  Consequently T and T? can be used as expected for non-nullable and nullable types.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use nullable in the constraint, but you can use it in the method signature. This effectively constraints it to be a nullable type. Example:

```
static Result<Nullable<T>> Create<T>(Nullable<T> value) where T  : struct
{
    //Do something
}
```

Note that you can use this side by side with your existing method, as an *overload*, which allows you to execute a different logic path if it's nullable versus if it is not.

```
static Result<Nullable<T>> Create<T>(Nullable<T> value) where T  : struct
{
    Log("It's nullable!");
    Foo(value);
}

public static Result<T> Create<T>(T value)
{
    Log("It's not nullable!");
    Foo(value);
}
```

Comment: There is `notnull` constraint like `Result<T> Create<T>(T value) where T  : notnull`, and I am trying to use the new nullable reference type instead of `Nullable<T>`

Comment: And this only considered `struct`. In our case, the generic type can be any class or struct. `T` may be `SomeClass` or `SomeClass?` or `SomeEnum` or `SomeEnum?` or `int?`, etc

Comment: But how would this handle a nullable reference type, like a string that may be null?

Answer (score -1):

The default value of reference types and nullable value types is null.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Non-nullables can never be null (obviously), so it stands to reason that you can simply do this:

```
public static bool IsNullable<T>() => default(T) == null;
```

This technique will not work if you are starting with a `System.Type` variable since it cannot be turned into a generic type param.