# c# 8 nullability - generic class "knowing" its nullability

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've got two classes - an inner class and an outer class, where the inner class can return a null value and an outer class that shouldn't (assuming, of course, that the type parameter T represents a non-nullable type):

```
#nullable enable
public class Insider<T>
{
    [MaybeNull, AllowNull]
    public T Value {get; set; }

    public Insider()
    { Value = default; }
}
public class Outsider<T>
{
    Insider<T> Inside = new Insider<T>();

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Inside.Value; // Compiler warning "'Value' may be null here"
        }
        set { Inside.Value = value; }
    }
}
public class Fred
{ }
public static class Test
{
    public static void Stuff()
    {
        Outsider<Fred> one = new Outsider<Fred>();
        Debug.WriteLine("one.Value is " + one.Value);

        Outsider<Fred?> two = new Outsider<Fred?>();
        Debug.WriteLine("two.Value is " + two.Value);

        Outsider<int> three = new Outsider<int>();
        Debug.WriteLine("three.Value is " + three.Value);
    }
}
#nullable disable
```

When I run this, it gives the expected output:

```
one.Value is
two.Value is
three.Value is 0
```

The program state that causes "Insider.Value" to be null is a specific error state, and the caller should know the system is in that state and not access "Outsider.Value", which means that caller should never see "Outsider.Value" return null, but I'd like to enforce that.

And yes, both classes should handle structs as well as classes.

What I was thinking, was something along these lines:

```
public class Outsider<T>
{
    Insider<T> Inside = new Insider<T>();

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if ((Inside.Value == null)&&(T_shouldnt_be_null))
                throw new Exception("Nope");
            return Inside.Value;
        }
        set { Inside.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

The troublesome part, of course, is the "T_shouldnt_be_null".

If I put more debugging in Outsider.Value:

```
public class Outsider<T>
{
    Insider<T> Inside = new Insider<T>();

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            Type? nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
            Debug.WriteLine("      typeof(T) is "  + typeof(T) + "; nullableType=" + ((nullableType==null)?"null": nullableType.ToString()));
            foreach (var x in typeof(T).CustomAttributes)
                Debug.WriteLine("         " + x);
            return Inside.Value;
        }
        set { Inside.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

I get results that were not what I expected.  The results when the type parameter T is Fred (non-nullable) are:

```
typeof(T) is BTSDataCollator.Fred; nullableType=null
```

and the results when the type parameter is Fred? (nullable) are:

```
typeof(T) is BTSDataCollator.Fred; nullableType=null
```

The compiler has completely stripped the nullability indicator from the type.  And in both cases the class type has no CustomAttributes (and that's what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type) relies on to determine nullability)

Is there any way that a (generic) class can get information on the nullability of its actual type parameter (Fred vs. Fred?) ?

Comment: `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` is for nullable value types.

Comment: Can't your ensure at compile time the T of Outsider is not nullable ? "public class Outsider<T> where T : struct". In that case you will have a compiler error if you try to use reference type (nullable).

Comment: Alas, as I said in my post, "both classes should handle structs as well as classes."

Comment: @GuruStron I was trying everything I could think of to "see" the nullability.  I expected that when I instantiated Outsider<Fred?> that T would be Nullable<Fred> but it wasn't.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Alas, I have printed out the CustomAttributes of typeof(T) as well as the CustomAttributes of Outsider's Value property and the CustomAttributes of the Outsider's Value property's PropertyType.  In every case there are -zero- CustomAttributes, which is what that StackOverflow post relies on

Comment: Side note on naming: usually one would use "Outer" and "Inner"... Outsider/Insider imply that there is access to some secret information ("insiders" are the one who have non-public information, "outsiders" are once without such knowledge with negative connotation) and not containment relationship...

Comment: @BettyCrokker Please, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62165259/12833205. I think that it can be helpful. It deals with `nullability` of the type parameter of the method (not class) but the problem is the same: *how to define if type parameter is nullable or not*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in general case what you are trying to do is impossible. If you check your code in [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) you will see that no information is added to generic class, so `new Outsider<Fred>()` and `new Outsider<Fred?>()` are exactly the same for compiler:

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        Outsider<Fred> one = new Outsider<Fred>();
        Outsider<Fred?> two = new Outsider<Fred?>();
    }
}
```

results in next IL:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
    // Code size 14 (0xe)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class Outsider`1<class Fred> one,
        [1] class Outsider`1<class Fred> two
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void class Outsider`1<class Fred>::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: newobj instance void class Outsider`1<class Fred>::.ctor()
    IL_000c: stloc.1
    IL_000d: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

So there is basically no information which you can get via reflection.

Comment: Argh.  That's good analysis.  I wonder though ... if I create two classes "class One : Outsider<Fred>" and "class Two : Outsider<Fred?>" inside a library, and then consume those classes outside of that library - doesn't that mean the signatures of "One" and "Two" have to somehow indicate their nullability?  I'm not familiar with libraries in the C# world so I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: Yes!  class One has a custom attribute [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute(new Byte[2] { 0, 1 })] while class Two has a custom attribute [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute(new Byte[2] { 0, 2 })].  You don't even have to be in a different library to see that, just have to create new subclasses.  Not sure how that helps ... yet ...

Comment: Ooh ... this would be some really wicked code ... I wonder what would happen if I defined a subclass using an Expression tree and then compiled it ...

Comment: @BettyCrokker I'm afraid you will need to use something like `Reflection.Emit`, not sure that you can declare classes with expression trees.

Comment: Yeah, even that was a no go.  I can create a class using AssemblyBuilder and TypeBuilder that derives from Outsider but you specify the base class as a Type, and the Type of Outsider<Fred> and Outsider<Fred?> are identical (even down to the same GUID)