# Cannot assign null to a nullable generic property

Tags: c#, nullable

Please consider the following code fragment:

```
    public class EntitiesViewModel<T> : BaseViewModel, IEntityAddable where T : IDataEntity, new()
    {
        private T? _SelectedEntity;
        public T? SelectedEntity
        {
            get => _SelectedEntity;
            set => SetProperty(ref _SelectedEntity, value);
        }

        private void RefreshView()
        {
            //... skipped not relevant code ...
            SelectedEntity = null; // <-- error right here (Cannot convert null to type parameter ‘T’ because it could be a non-nullable value type)
           
        }
    }
```

This can be solved by providing an explicit `class` constraint:

```
public class EntitiesViewModel<T> : BaseViewModel, IEntityAddable where T : class, IDataEntity, new()
```

But why does this happen? I already define `SelectedEntity` as nullable by using `?`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify a nullable reference type for generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165259/how-to-identify-a-nullable-reference-type-for-generic-type)

Comment: No, not really. There they ask how to identify if `T` is nullable. In my case my question is why the compiler does not allow me to set a property of type `T?` to null. I am explicitly marking it as nullable. This should work even if `T` is a struct or any other non-nullable type

Comment: It comes down to the same reason: because if you don't use the `class` constraint then the compiler doesn't know if it's a value type or a reference type. Therefore it cannot apply the compiler mod flag for nullable reference types. Essentially, nullable value types and nullable reference types are so different in the way they are implemented that they cannot be mixed using generics. You must specify the constraint.

Comment: I see, thanks for the follow up. You were right about the linked question, it is indeed closely related.