# C# detect nullable reference type from generic argument of method's return type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-6.0, c#-9.0

I have this simple interface in .net-6/C#9 with nullable reference types turned on:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Task<MyModel?> GetMyModel();
}
```

How do I detect by reflection that the generic argument `MyModel` of method's return type is in fact declared as nullable reference type `MyModel?` ?

#### What i tried...

```cs
typeof(IMyInterface).GetMethods()[0].ReturnType...??
```

I tried using [`NullabilityInfoContext`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-7/#libraries-reflection-apis-for-nullability-information) but the `Create` method accepts `PropertyInfo`, `ParameterInfo`, `FieldInfo`, `EventInfo` which does not really help here or I can't figure out how.

The solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type) also accepts only `PropertyInfo`, `FieldInfo` and `EventInfo`

I also tried observing the attributes from `method.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0]` but there is no difference between methods that return `Task<MyModel>` and `Task<MyModel?>`

[image: custom attributes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MethodInfo.ReturnParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.returnparameter?view=net-6.0) for `NullabilityInfoContext`:

```cs
Type type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(nameof(IMyInterface.GetMyModel));

NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
var nullabilityInfo = context.Create(methodInfo.ReturnParameter); // return type
var genericTypeArguments = nullabilityInfo.GenericTypeArguments;
var myModelNullabilityInfo = genericTypeArguments.First(); // nullability info for generic argument of Task
Console.WriteLine(myModelNullabilityInfo.ReadState);    // Nullable
Console.WriteLine(myModelNullabilityInfo.WriteState);   // Nullable
```

To analyze nullable attributes `methodInfo.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes.GetCustomAttributes(true)` can be used.

Comment: What about generic methods with an (unconstrained) type-parameter, but `void` return-type and no method parameters? e.g. `static void Foo<T>() {  }` as `Foo<String>()` vs `Foo<String?>()`?