# Can you tell by Reflection which string is nullable and which is not?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have these 2 types:

1. `Type nrvt = typeof(List<string?>);` // nullable string generic argument
2. `Type nnrvt = typeof(List<string>);` // non-nullable string generic argument

Can I tell *(via Reflection)* which has nullable and which has non-nullable strings in `.NET 6`?

There's a `NullabilityInfoContext` but handles object-related stuff *(Properties, Fields, Events and Parameters)*. Not finding anything for this case.

Comment: Even if it's not achievable for regular Variables, for Class Properties it works. Even for these very types I mentioned, if they are Properties of an object you can find the nullability: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549957/1451110 in `NullabilityInfo.GenericTypeArguments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The IL for both constructs is the same ([SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANnAJiA1AHwAIBMAjALABQeADAAR5EAsA3OeQMQwCuKKEwKAptX4xeAlhQDMtAtQDC1AN7lqK2lLz1qAcX4IAclx59+AFQCeAB34AKAJSLlqp+avUYAJwBuCagF5qCJb8APYAZtYAMlAAzggAPHSUAPwAfLbMZE4Avo4qeOqaOvrBMAbcoqZBdg6ZTqougjAe3n4BQWGRMfGJaRnZ5FlAA=)):

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldtoken class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>
IL_0006: call class [System.Runtime]System.Type [System.Runtime]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_000b: stloc.0
IL_000c: ret
```

where local variable 0 is `class [System.Runtime]System.Type`. So when compiled there is no difference between the two expressions.

Comment: I assumed it's like this. Thanks for the sharplab.io hint! Used it several times when I needed to emit some IL but didn't think to use it to check this.

Answer (score 2):

No, `nrvt` and `nnrvt` are the same type.

[Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) are only a compiler instruction intended to prevent warnings about objects potentially being null in a #nullable conext.

`string?` is not creating a `Nullable<string>` the way that `int?` creates a `Nullable<int>`. In fact, `Nullable<string>` is not even a valid type, given  `Nullable<>`'s type constraint of `where T : struct`.

Comment: I know `Nullable<>` only works with value types so it doesn't apply to `string`. But I hoped there's some metadata/attributes I'm missing that would advertise the nullability of reference types.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it applies to your question, but I was able to distinguish by looking at the `PropertyInfo.PropertyType.CustomAttributes`.

In my test setup, I have a test class with a property of the `string` type and another one of type nullable string (`string?`). The latter one has a custom attribute of type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute((Byte)2)` while the former one is missing that custom attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use `NullableAttribute` to differentiate between the two strings.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).