# Are nullable reference types not Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types, c#-10.0

I created a new C#10/.net6 library project in VS2022 using the standard template, NRTs are enabled by default (nullable : enabled). I notice that nullable reference types do not appear to support `Nullable` properties `Value` and `HasValue`

[MRE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9yBj27) (using #nullable annotation explicitly)

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
#nullable enable
        object? o =null;
        if(o.HasValue)
        {}
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no
> accessible extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of
> type 'object' could be found

Are nullable reference types not actually `Nullable<T>`? `o` is declared as `object?` so why does the compiler refer to `object` rather than `object?`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

> However, nullable reference types and nullable value types are implemented differently: nullable value types are implemented using `System.Nullable<T>`, and nullable reference types are implemented by attributes read by the compiler. For example, `string?` and `string` are both represented by the same type: `System.String`. However, `int?` and `int` are represented by `System.Nullable<System.Int32>` and `System.Int32`, respectively.

Basically NRT is just compile time information (though you can get access it in runtime via reflection like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549957/2501279)).

As for the case - just use ordinary null check and that's it.

```
if(o != null)
{

}
```

or pattern matching:

```cs
if(o is {} notNullO)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second example `notNull0` but thanks this is clear - missed that detail. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Boy was glad to help! `is {}` checks that object [is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140081/2501279) and creates alias variable for the checked. It is not required in general case but AFAIK one time I got some corner case when compiler needed it.