# Why does nullability check not work with value types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, nullable, nullable-reference-types

Given the following code samples:

```cs
class Value { }

Value? value = null;

if (value is not null)
{
    Value value2 = value;
}
```

```cs
int? value = null;

if (value is not null)
{
    int value2 = value; // CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.
}
```

I understand the issue has to do with reference types vs value types.

However, in both cases I am checking whether `value` is null, so why can the compiler not understand that value should never be null inside the if block in the second example?

I can remedy the issue by using `value.Value`, but this seems counterintuitive.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Quite simply because the types don't match.

Comment: Value types use `INullable<T>`, and this is distinct from nullable reference types. The compiler does not treat them the same way, and this can lead to unexpected behaviors like this. So while I agree that his is counterintuitive, I do not think there is any good solution other than using `value.Value`.

Comment: You null check it, but as @phuzi states the type is still Nullable. You would have to get the value `value.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: Why don't you simply assign value to `value2` like this: `int value2 = value.HasValue ? value.Value : default;` or in more concise format: `int value2 = value ?? default;`

Comment: @PeterCsala The samples are minimal reproductions of the actual code I was writing. The original code involved nullable DateTimes and adding them to a dictionary if they are not null.

Comment: @JonasH - `INullable<T>` you meant `Nullable<T>` I assume?

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) in C#/.NET are represented via a separate type ([`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0)), i.e. `int?` is actually is `Nullable<int>`. You can use pattern matching. For example:

```
if (value is {} value2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value2);
}
```

Or

```cs
if (value is int value2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value2);
}
```

Or just access the `Nullable.Value`:

```
if (value is not null)
{
    int value2 = value.Value;
}
```

[Nullable references types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) on the other hand are not represented via a separate type (i.e. `string?` from the type info point of view is `string` and nullability information is stored in some kind of metadata - see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549957/2501279)), i.e. one could argue that some kind of type erasure is happening in this case.