# Generic property type in intercace and nullable error

Tags: c#, generics, interface, nullable

Non generic interface has no issue with nullable mark.
In generic interface below marking TKey as nullable generates compiler error.
Why ? And is it possible to mark generic property type as nullable ?

> Error CS0738  'TClass' does not implement interface member
> 'ITest.Info1'. 'TClass.Info1' cannot implement 'ITest.Info1'
> because it does not have the matching return type of 'int'.

```
    public interface ITest<TKey>
{
    public TKey? Info1 { get; set; }
    public BHPGuard.Domain.LocationType.LocationType? Type { get; set; }

}

public class TClass : ITest<int>
{
    public int? Info1 { get; set; }
    public LocationType.LocationType? Type { get; set; }
    // int ITest<int>.Info1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ?

The problem here is that `TKey` is unconstrained generic type, so for value types `TKey?` is `TKey`, so to implement the interface you can do:

```
public class TClass : ITest<int>
{
    public int Info1 { get; set; }
    public LocationType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class TClass : ITest<int?>
{
    public int? Info1 { get; set; }
    public LocationType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can constrain the generic parameter to be a struct:

```
public interface ITest<TKey> where TKey : struct
{
    public TKey? Info1 { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

> is it possible to mark generic property type as nullable ?

Yes, but due to the difference of how nullable reference and nullable value types are treated (the later are actually represented via type `Nullable<T>` while former are not) it has quite some limitations in terms of how it will behave depending on the constraints defined.

See [Nullability and generics in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72911604/2501279)  and [Why does nullability check not work with value types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76953054/2501279) for more info.