# Check if PropertyType is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have followed this example : [enter link description here](https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/06/20/c-check-if-propertytype-is-null/) to check if PropertyType is Null. However, it seems all attempts are yielding the wrong output.

The Candidate Class was generated by Scaffolding.

```
public partial class Candidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
}
```

**Function to Check for Nullable Property:**

```
    public static bool CheckPro()
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Candidate).GetProperties();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] readableProperties = properties.Where(w => w.CanRead).ToArray();
        foreach (var property in readableProperties)
        {
            var propertyType = property.PropertyType;          
            if (System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(property.Name + " -> Nullable type ");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(property.Name + " ->NOT nullable type ");
            }
        }
    //}
        return false;
    }
```

**OutPut:**

Only `DateOfBirth` is declared as Nullable Type.

```
Id ->NOT nullable type 
FirstName ->NOT nullable type 
MiddleName ->NOT nullable type 
LastName ->NOT nullable type 
DateOfBirth -> Nullable type 
Gender ->NOT nullable type
```

The Expected Output is `MiddleName`, `DateOfBirth`,  `Gender` to be of Nullable Type. The goal here is to determine that the `FirstName` and `LastName` should not be null at the database level when trying to save.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use .NET reflection to check for nullable reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type) To a first approximation, if available in your version of .NET, use `NullabilityInfoContext`, which covers both value and reference types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. This worked `new NullabilityInfoContext().Create(p).WriteState is NullabilityState.Nullable`. Do you think this approach is considered a good implementation to check the required fields of Entity?

Comment: `NullabilityInfoContext` uses some built-in caching for the `Create` methods, which is why it's an instance and not just a bunch of static methods. From a performance perspective it's probably slightly better to use one instance to check all properties of a type, rather than creating a new one for every property, so you may want to rewrite the method(s) that call `CheckPro` (which is a really bad name in terms of conveying meaning, incidentally).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thank you again. Very very helpful insights. I hope I understand what you mean. So in my helper static class i have added `private static NullabilityInfoContext NullInfoContext = new NullabilityInfoContext();`. Instead of creating a new instance everytime I check a property.  And have changed the name as well of `CheckPro`