# CSharp: Check if Reference Type is Nullable Reference Type

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Microsoft has introduces [Nullable Reference Types with C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

The nullable checks work only for your own Code, but if you Deserialize a class, some values can be null despite your property does not allow it. (Because you can't control the 'outside world')

In that case, we have to check for null even it is normally not possible.

I'd like to do a automation that checks after deserialization all "NotNullable" reference types if they're really not null.

I didn't found any **official solution** to check if the reference type is a nullable or not, so I came up with the following solution:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public string NotNullable { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Nullable { get; set; }
}
```

Quick check as follows:

```cs
var properties = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, IsNullable: {1}",
        property.Name,
        (!property.PropertyType.IsValueType 
          && property.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute")));

}
```

Output for Debug and Release Build are the same:

```
Property: NotNullable, IsNullable: False
Property: Nullable, IsNullable: True
```

**Any idea, if there is a better (maybe an official) solution without checking for a hardcoded "NullableAttribute" string?**

Comment: The *official* solution is in the linked question: `NullabilityInfoContext` (be sure to read not merely the main body of the accepted answer).

Comment: I can't use the latest .Net version, so my solution looks as follows:

`var type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

isNullable = nullableType is not null 
    || (!type.IsValueType
        && propertyInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute"));`

Comment: The Nullable check is wrong, it should be `a => a.ToString() == "[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute((Byte)2)]")`

Comment: The [linked question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454489/41379160) actually has a correct implementation for the case where `NullabilityInfoContext` is not available. Bottom line, it's not as simple as just checking for `NullableAttribute`, because it might be applied to the type instead. You seem to be reinventing the wheel for no good reason.