# How to determine whether a reference-based generic parameter is nullable

Tags: c#, reflection

Generally, using C# reflection I've been able to get every detail that's ever been needed about a type. I've recently encountered a specific use-case that I have not been able to reflect: reference-based generic parameter nullability.

For example, given:

```
    public class ReflectMe
    {
        public List<long?> Ids0 { get; set; } = new List<long?>();

        [NullParam(true)]
        public List<String?> Names0 { get; set; } = new List<String?>();

        public List<long?>? Ids1 { get; set; } = new List<long?>();

        [NullParam(true)]
        [NullParam(true)]
        public List<List<String?>?>? Names1 { get; set; } = new List<List<string?>?>();
    }
```

The `Ids0` and `Ids1` can be reflected (via either `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` or `NullabilityInfoContext`) since the inner `long` is a value-type. However, `Names0` 's `String` cannot be reflected, and `Names1`'s inner `List` and `String` cannot be reflected.

*The `NullParam` attribute was created as a work-around but is obviously not ideal.*

*Using C# v 11 (.NET 7.0) with Nullable enabled.*

Any ideas about how this can be achieved?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-variable-annotations You can't see it because it isn't there. Nullable reference type have no representation to the CLR, it doesn't know about them. It's pretty much a compile time static analysis feature.

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate question; the other question is about first-level reference nullability, not generic parameters. The described techniques are not applicable.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md shows how it is stored in the associated `NullableAttribute` if there are generic parameters. Also you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/68757807/14868997 `NullabilityInfo` which has properties for the generic arguments.