# How to Determine Nullability (NRT) of Type T (NOT Duplicate)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

If I have a class like this:

```
public class Something<T>
{
    public Type SaveType { get; set; }

    public Something()
    {
        SaveType = typeof(T);
    }
}
```

If somebody calls this as `new Something<int?>()`, then `SaveType` is `Nullable<int>`  But if somebody calls it as `new Something<string?>()`, then `SaveType` is just `String`.  Obviously that's because string is a reference type.  But I want my class to know that the person expects it as an NRT.  So how do I figure out how the consumer called it?

Other (seemingly duplicate, but not?) answers talk about using `NullabilityInfoContext` to find out the types of properties, events, parameters, etc.  But I don't see how to use that here.

Comment: You can get the default value of T then check this value:

var a = default(T);
if(a is null)
   // todo

Comment: @Den Default value of a reference type will be null whether or not it is declared with a ? though.

Comment: mmm you have right....

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you have something broken in your design. You shouldn't care once the generic type has been constructed. If you want to restrict to only non-null types then use `where T : notnull`.

Comment: I am using .NET 7.

Comment: My design is not broken.  `default(T)` is broken.  If T is `string?` (or `string` prior to NRT), then `default(T)` should be `null`.  But `default(T)` for a Not-Nullable Reference Type `string` using the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` option should no longer be `null`.  I realize NRT's are compile time syntactical sugar for the most part, but they have real issues for consumers of libraries.

Comment: I do not wish to limit the use of the class to `where T : notnull`.  I want a consumer to be able to use the class either as `Something<string>` or as `Something<string?>`, and my handling will be different in either case.  But I don't know how to tell which way the consumer instantiated the class.

Comment: "should no longer be null" - but which value? I can sort of guess your answer for `string` but what would it be for arbitrary reference types?

Comment: Ooooh, good question.  Then again, one big benefit of every reference type inheriting from `object` is its association with `null`ability.  In moving away from `null`, perhaps classes should be required to have empty constructors or literally "default" constructors.  But apart from theorycrafting, I just want to know which type they passed in.  My code will indeed decide what to do them if they ask for `new Something<MyClass?>()`.  I just need to know if they're using `MyClass` or `MyClass?`.

Comment: Since NRT is just syntactic sugar, there is no such thing as `default(T)` which is different from `default(T?)`. The best you can do is put a constraint `where T : new()` (or require a factory method) so that you can always construct a `T` where needed. Forget about nullability for the moment and look at the problem in the other direction: what value do you want as a default, does the caller need to provide one?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) has some precise wording about *nullable reference types* are that is perhaps a bit vague

> Improved static flow analysis that determines if a variable may be `null` before dereferencing it.

That is, metadata available to the compiler to emit warnings about potential null reference exceptions. But that information is not available at runtime.

See perhaps [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1087#issuecomment-567935260) from a dotnet runtime maintainer

> Nullable reference types are present in the assembly as attributes and are used by the compiler with flow analysis to identify violations of the stated use. Nullable value types are supported by the Nullable type and are a runtime feature.

To the runtime, a *nullable reference type* is the same as the underlying type. This is different than with structs; for example, a `Nullable<int>` is a different type than `int`. But for `class SomeClass`, then the type for `SomeClass?` is the same as the type for `SomeClass` (note that `typeof(SomeClass?)` is a compile error).

But really, what problem are you trying to solve? If you are saving the type information, it will no longer be associated with a variable/property/field/etc which is the thing that might be assigned `null`, so there's nothing for the compiler to track any more (as far as potential null reference exceptions).

---

That is how it works for runtime `Type` information, and `typeof` is essentially runtime type information. If you can promote whatever you are trying to track to a property, field, or parameter, then you can access the *nullable* attribute information at compile time like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454489/1462295).

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public SomeClass PropSomeClass { get; set; }
    public SomeClass? PropSomeClassMaybe { get; set; }
}
public class Something<T>
{
    public Type SaveType { get; set; }

    public Something()
    {
        SaveType = typeof(T);
    }
}
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // declare Something, with non-nullable reference SomeClass generic.
        // "nullable reference type" information isn't available to runtime.
        var somethingClass = new Something<SomeClass>();
        Console.WriteLine($"somethingClass: nullable reference type: {somethingClass.SaveType.Name}, {IsNullableHelper(somethingClass.SaveType, somethingClass.SaveType, new List<CustomAttributeData>())}");

        // declare Something, with nullable reference SomeClass generic
        // "nullable reference type" information isn't available to runtime.
        var somethingClassMaybe = new Something<SomeClass?>();
        Console.WriteLine($"somethingClassMaybe: nullable reference type: {somethingClassMaybe.SaveType.Name}, {IsNullableHelper(somethingClassMaybe.SaveType, somethingClassMaybe.SaveType, new List<CustomAttributeData>())}");

        var sc = new SomeClass();

        // non-nullable reference PropSomeClass
        // "nullable reference type" information available
        var prop1 = sc.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(SomeClass.PropSomeClass));

        // nullable reference PropSomeClassMaybe
        // "nullable reference type" information available
        var prop2 = sc.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(SomeClass.PropSomeClassMaybe));
        Console.WriteLine($"SomeClass.PropSomeClass: nullable reference type: {IsNullableHelper(prop1.PropertyType, typeof(SomeClass), prop1.CustomAttributes)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"SomeClass.PropSomeClassMaybe: nullable reference type: {IsNullableHelper(prop2.PropertyType, typeof(SomeClass), prop2.CustomAttributes)}");
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454489/1462295
    private static bool IsNullableHelper(Type memberType, MemberInfo? declaringType, IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> customAttributes)
    {
        if (memberType.IsValueType)
            return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(memberType) != null;

        var nullable = customAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.FullName == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute");
        if (nullable != null && nullable.ConstructorArguments.Count == 1)
        {
            var attributeArgument = nullable.ConstructorArguments[0];
            if (attributeArgument.ArgumentType == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                var args = (ReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument>)attributeArgument.Value!;
                if (args.Count > 0 && args[0].ArgumentType == typeof(byte))
                {
                    return (byte)args[0].Value! == 2;
                }
            }
            else if (attributeArgument.ArgumentType == typeof(byte))
            {
                return (byte)attributeArgument.Value! == 2;
            }
        }

        for (var type = declaringType; type != null; type = type.DeclaringType)
        {
            var context = type.CustomAttributes
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.FullName == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute");
            if (context != null &&
                context.ConstructorArguments.Count == 1 &&
                context.ConstructorArguments[0].ArgumentType == typeof(byte))
            {
                return (byte)context.ConstructorArguments[0].Value! == 2;
            }
        }

        // Couldn't find a suitable attribute
        return false;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
somethingClass: nullable reference type: SomeClass, False
somethingClassMaybe: nullable reference type: SomeClass, False
SomeClass.PropSomeClass: nullable reference type: False
SomeClass.PropSomeClassMaybe: nullable reference type: True
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, there's no difference at runtime between passing e.g. `string` and `string?`.

Consider the following:

```cs
new Something<string>();
new Something<string?>();

class Something<T> {}
```

This produces the following IL:

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void class Something`1<string>::.ctor()
IL_0005: pop
IL_0006: newobj instance void class Something`1<string>::.ctor()
IL_000b: pop
IL_000c: ret
```

As you can see, there's no difference between the two `new` (i.e. `newobj`) calls.

[Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHxgUwO4AIDKA9mJggBawDmAPAAICMADAHwAUAlANwCwAUFniIlyVOkwD8bLnz60ATAWKkKMGgBVmuAN4BfPkA===)