# How to determine if `object?` is nullable?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

The following test fails:

```cs
#nullable enable
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

public class TypeExtensionsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestIsNullable()
    {
        object? o = new();
        var type = o.GetType();

        bool isNullable = type.IsNullable();

        isNullable.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
    }
}
```

How to reliably establish that a `Type` instance is actually a nullable type?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type) does not answer my question, since the top answer is the implementation of the failing test.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which answer is the implementation you've already done? Is [this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2mXI5) not what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` is only applicable for _Value_ types, not reference types, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454489/1043380)

Comment: "This is an obligatory sentence to circumvent an error saying that this message does not contain enough content"—I know this has already been edited out, but please don't ever do this. It just creates work for other users. If you're prompted for more detail, _add more detail_.