# C#: how to check if a property type is string? (nullable string) or string

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, nullable-reference-types

giving this code:

```
var t = typeof(Sample);
var p1 = t.GetProperty(nameof(Sample.Str1));
var p2 = t.GetProperty(nameof(Sample.Str2));

Console.WriteLine(p1!.PropertyType == p2!.PropertyType);

public class Sample
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? Str2 { get; set; }
}
```

in a dotnet project with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in csproj
it prints "True"

but using int instead of string it shows "False".

Is there any way to know if the propertyType is the source code is "string" or "string?" ?

Comment: For **reference** types, the nullable annotation `?` basically is just a hint to the compiler whether the value might or might not be null.  It gets used to emit compiler warnings about missing null checks.  As such the actual declared return type is the same.  So, to check for reference nullability, see [How to use .NET reflection to check for nullable reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58453972).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes that answer my question