Determine if a reference type is nullable at runtime
In C# it's trivial to determine whether a value type is nullable. Specifically, you can obtain this information from the Type itself; for example:
public static bool IsNullable(this Type type) =>
    type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) is not null;

As I understand, it's possible to obtain nullability information for nullable reference types via NullableAttribute or NullableContextAttribute, but it would appear that this has to be obtained from MemberInfo, rather than from the Type.
Is this understanding correct, or is there a workaround to obtain nullability information for nullable reference types from a Type?

Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453972/how-to-use-net-reflection-to-check-for-nullable-reference-type The question is a bit unclear, a string? is not a different type than string, so there is no way to check if it's a nullable reference type. You can just check it if you have the MemberInfo

a type, in the context of a class / reference-type, does not know whether it is even being used in a NRT-enabled context, let alone what the final NRT designation is; so: no, this is not possible from a Type. The MemberInfo: is more contextual, so: yup

It is precisely because you cannot obtain nullability information from Type that NullableAttribute  and NullableContextAttribute are introduced.

You don't write public class Foo? { } or similar. You create a class Foo, and then variables / fields / parameters / etc have a type which is Foo or Foo?. Therefore, it is not the type itself which is nullable, but the variable / field / parameter which uses that type. Therefore, it makes sense that you can't get nullability information from a Type, because such a thing wouldn't make any sense

It's not a duplicate.  The other question asks, "Is there a way to check a class property uses a nullable reference type via reflection?", to which the answer is yes.  The current question asks about doing it from a Type, which is not possible.

Nullable reference types (C# reference):

Nullable reference types aren't new class types, but rather
annotations on existing reference types. The compiler uses those
annotations to help you find potential null reference errors in your
code. There's no runtime difference between a non-nullable reference
type and a nullable reference type.

That's the reason why you can't use typeof on a nullable reference type:
Type t = typeof(string?); // error CS8639

So you need a PropertyInfo or FieldInfo if you want to check if it's nullable, for example:
public static bool IsMarkedAsNullable(PropertyInfo p)
{
    return new NullabilityInfoContext().Create(p).WriteState is NullabilityState.Nullable;
}

Copied extension from here: How to use .NET reflection to check for nullable reference type

I'd hazard a guess that given a Type instance, there is also no way to obtain the MemberInfo? that declared the type, without any other information than the Type itself?

@MatthewLayton: No, a System.Type has just information about the type itself, not about where it is used(it can be used in any context, sometimes nullable and sometimes not).
